# apache spark delete element from column of arraytype

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file with two columns:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  c1 |    location                                      |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1  |[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]                                 |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using Spark to load this CSV file using

```
DataSet<Row> dataset = spark.read.format("csv").csv(pathOfCsvFile);
```

Is there a way to delete list of elements like `1,2,3` from the imported column location so the result is :

```
{
  "c1" : "1" ,
  "location" : {
               [4,5,6,7,8]
             }
}
```

Comment: my real case that i have a list of coordinates i need to delete coordinates to simplify the geometry of my line.so we can say delete from location where in [1,2,3]

Comment: then where are 7 and 8 in the final output?

Comment: yes result 4,5,6,7,8

Comment: You'll need a UDF, I think.

Comment: i try to write UDF ,but my problem was how to delete from the column of type array

Comment: You can't delete anything, you'll need to create a new column and select only the required ones from `location`

Comment: Yes I agree with philantrovert. Try UDF

Comment: do you have any example how i do that.

Comment: can i have some  help to write a UDF to delete from column  of type array using java code ?? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a UDF to do that for you.

Suppose the list of elements you want to delete looks like:

```scala
val ys = Seq(1,2,3)
```

And, you input dataframe:

```scala
+---+------------------------+
|a  |b                       |
+---+------------------------+
|1  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]|
+---+------------------------+
```

You need to remove elements from Column `b` that are present in the Sequence `ys`

```scala
val filterList = udf( (xs: Seq[Int], ys: Seq[Int]) => xs.filterNot(ys.contains(_) ) )
```

And then, call it on your dataframe like :

```scala
df.withColumn("location" , filterList($"location" , array(b.map(lit _) :_* ) )).show(false)

+---+---------------+
|a  |location       |
+---+---------------+
|1  |[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]|
+---+---------------+
```

Comment: thanks you,its so helpful ..one thing more if u please can u write this example using java code